# How to fix UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-19 when trying to run python3 function in node-red

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, node-red

I'm trying to run an empty python3 function (only `return msg` is in it) in node-red with the node 'node-red-contrib-python3-function', but I get the error mentioned in the title. I have Python 3.7.3 installed atm. The error message received is (repeats 10 times):

```
10 Apr 13:55:38 - [info] [python3-function:TEST] Python function 'TEST' running on PID 4616
10 Apr 13:55:40 - [info] [python3-function:TEST] Raw message received: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00{"topic":"","payload":1554897340119,"_msgid":"c6460d66.0d218"}\n'

10 Apr 13:55:40 - [error] [python3-function:TEST] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 72, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 343, in loads
    s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\encodings\utf_32_le.py", line 11, in decode
    return codecs.utf_32_le_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-19: code point not in range(0x110000)

10 Apr 13:55:40 - [error] [python3-function:TEST] Python Function process exited with code 1
10 Apr 13:55:40 - [info] [python3-function:TEST] Python function 'TEST' running on PID 8640
10 Apr 13:55:42 - [info] [python3-function:TEST] Raw message received: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00{"topic":"","payload":1554897342120,"_msgid":"d57b8b5f.5ef468"}\n'

10 Apr 13:55:42 - [error] [python3-function:TEST] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 72, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 343, in loads
    s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\encodings\utf_32_le.py", line 11, in decode
    return codecs.utf_32_le_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-19: code point not in range(0x110000)

10 Apr 13:55:42 - [error] [python3-function:TEST] Python Function process exited with code 1
```

The following code is ran by the node (found in python3-function.js in that node modules lib folder) when the flow is deployed, I've added the printing of the raw message myself.

```py
def python_function(msg):
` + indentLines(config.func, 4) +
                `
while True:
    raw_msg = channel.readline()
    print(f"Raw message received: {raw_msg}")
    if not raw_msg:
        raise RuntimeError('Received EOF!')
    msg = json.loads(raw_msg)
    msgid = msg["_msgid"]
    node = Node(msgid, channel)
    res_msgs = python_function(msg)
    node.send(res_msgs)
`
```

Where channel is:

```
channel = None
if sys.version_info[0]<3:
    channel = os.fdopen(3, "r+")
else:
    channel = os.fdopen(3, "rb", buffering=0)
```

Node is defined as:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, msgid, channel):
        self.__msgid = msgid
        self.__channel = channel

    def send(self, msg):
        msg = Msg(Msg.SEND, msg, self.__msgid)
        self.send_to_node(msg)

    def log(self, *args):
        msg = Msg(Msg.LOG, args, self.__msgid)
        self.send_to_node(msg)

    def warn(self, *args):
        msg = Msg(Msg.WARN, args, self.__msgid)
        self.send_to_node(msg)

    def error(self, *args):
        msg = Msg(Msg.ERROR, args, self.__msgid)
        self.send_to_node(msg)

    def status(self, *args):
        msg = Msg(Msg.STATUS, args, self.__msgid)
        self.send_to_node(msg)

    def send_to_node(self, msg):
        m = msg.dumps()
        if sys.version_info[0]>2:
            m = m.encode("utf-8")
        self.__channel.write(m)
```

Comment: Your issue here is that the return object from `channel.readline()` is not pure JSON. It has a couple of bytes in front, which cannot be converted back into utf-32 encoding. So look into whoever's sending the message to the channel

Comment: I can't change whatever is sent to that channel. I have no idea how node-red works in that way. I guess my best bet would be to try and just remove the bytes before the '{', if possible.